# How to open a new frame from a current window in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class Login:
    def __init__(self):
        Label1 = Label(root,text = "Username")
        Label2 = Label(root,text = "Password")
        self.Entry1 = Entry(root)
        self.Entry2 = Entry(root,show = "*")

        Label1.grid(row=0)
        Label2.grid(row=1)

        self.Entry1.grid(row = 0,column = 1)
        self.Entry2.grid(row = 1,column = 1)

        root.minsize(width = 300,height = 80)
        ##new_window_button = Button(text="new window", command = ????)
        ##new_window_button.grid(columnspan = 2)

        lgbutton = Button(text = "Login",command = self.ButtonClicked)
        lgbutton.grid(columnspan = 2)


    def ButtonClicked(self):
            username = self.Entry1.get()
            password = self.Entry2.get()
            GetDatabase(username,password)
```

Currently this is what I have to create a window, however I want it to that when the new_window_button is clicked, the new page has its own widgets. I've used Toplevel before but it creates a child window without the widgets. Instead, the widgets are added to the parent window.

Comment: So, you know how to create a new toplevel, and your only complaint is the title? Have you done any research to see how to change the title of a window?

Comment: Have you tried the same method that changes the root windows title on your Toplevel window?

Comment: No, the title name is not an issue, obviously I have that solved now. But when I create a new window, and create new widgets, the widgets are added to the parent.

Comment: If the widgets are appearing in the wrong window, you're giving them the wrong parent.  That's the first parameter to every widget constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the comments it looks as though you are struggling with declaring the correct parent for widgets.

When a widget is declared the first parameter passed in to it is it's parent. For example:

```
Label(root, text="I'm in the root window.")
#      ^ This is the parent
```

As opposed to:

```
Label(top, text="I'm in the top window.")
#      ^ This is the parent
```

Please see a more fleshed out example below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

top = Toplevel(root)

label1 = Label(root, text="I'm a placeholder in your root window.")
label2 = Label(top, text="I'm a placeholder in your top window.")

label1.pack()
label2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter

from tkinter import *

class LoginForm(Frame):
 def __init__(self,master=None):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.pack()
    self.createWidget()

 def createWidget(self):
    self.lblEmailId=Label(self,text="Email Id")
    self.lblEmailId.grid(row=0,column=0)
    self.varEmailid=StringVar()
    self.txtEmailId=Entry(self,textvariable=self.varEmailid)
    self.txtEmailId.grid(row=0,column=1)
    self.txtEmailId.bind("<KeyRelease>",self.key_press)

    self.lblPassword = Label(self, text="Password")
    self.lblPassword.grid(row=1, column=0)
    self.varPassword=StringVar()

    self.txtPassword= Entry(self, textvariable=self.varPassword)
    self.txtPassword.grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.btnLogin=Button(self,text="Login")
    self.btnLogin.grid(row=2,column=1)
    self.btnLogin.bind("<Button-1>",self.btnLogin_click)

 def btnLogin_click(self,event):
    self.varPassword.set(self.varEmailid.get())
    LoginWindow=Toplevel()






 def key_press(self,event):
    self.varPassword.set(self.varEmailid.get())


root=Tk()
fromLogin=LoginForm(root)
root.mainloop()
```